# USB cdc_acm driver not assigning Data interface to any port

Tags: usb, serial-port, usb-device

I have a USB CDC-ACM device emulating Serial over USB communication. The CDC Communications and Data interfaces are shown respectively on 2-1:1.0 (Comm) and 2-1:1.1 (Data) interface descriptors, and the `cdc_acm` driver is being loaded properly.

My issue is that only the Communication interface is being assigned to `/dev/ttyACMX` by `cdc_acm` driver, but the Data interface is ignored. It seems to prevents the device from working properly (a GBA ST2 Bill Validator using ccTalk protocol). It works fine on Windows 8+ using the `usbser.sys` driver.

With `cdc_acm` driver, dmesg and lsusb output is:

```
$ dmesg
[ 3484.982436] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-pci
[ 3485.251788] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=16f9, idProduct=0003
[ 3485.251792] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3485.251794] usb 2-1: Product: GBA ST2
[ 3485.251795] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Astrosystems
[ 3485.251796] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 06010010001
[ 3485.260103] cdc_acm 2-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device

$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/12p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/12p, 480M
```

Showing that:

- 2-1:1.0 is assigned to `/dev/ttyACM0`
- 2-1:1.1 is ignored

By playing around with the `usbserial` driver to assign the Data interface to a `/dev/ttyUSBX` port I found that the following manipulation *sometimes* works:

1. plug-in the device and have it use the `cdc_acm` driver. This cause the device to exit its sleep mode (the device leds becomes green)
2. Switch to the `usbserial` driver using `modprobe -r cdc_acm
   && modprobe usbserial vendor=0x16f9 product=0x0003`, resulting in the Comm interface being ignored and Data interface assigned to a USB port
3. If the device goes back to sleep mode, it needs to be re-plugged and initialized again from step 1

When using the `usbserial` driver:

- 2-1:1.0 is ignored
- 2-1:1.1 is assigned to `/dev/ttyUSBX`

Related dmesg and lsusb:

```
$ dmesg
[ 3688.481125] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.0: Generic device with no bulk out, not allowed.
[ 3688.481153] usbserial_generic: probe of 2-1:1.0 failed with error -5
[ 3688.481157] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.1: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
[ 3688.481158] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.1: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
[ 3688.481160] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.1: generic converter detected
[ 3688.481219] usb 2-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0

$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/12p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=usbserial_generic, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/12p, 480M
```

My guess is that the device use the CDC Communication interface to perform some sort of initialization, and then the CDC Data interface when in use.

How can I have both interfaces attached to a USB and/or ACM port? Should I implement my own driver (or extend the cdc_acm driver) to explicitely attach each descriptor to a USB or ACM port?

Here is a sample `lsusb` -v output showing the Communication interface on 2-1:1.0 and Data interface on 2-1:1.1:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 16f9:0003
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            2 Communications
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x16f9
  idProduct          0x0003
  bcdDevice           14.06
  iManufacturer           1 Astrosystems
  iProduct                2 GBA ST2
  iSerial                 3 06010010001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           62
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              4 GBA USB Serial Port
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.20
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x02
          line coding and serial state
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval              50
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              4 GBA USB Serial Port
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```